# how to push input text value to checkbox value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

**View Table**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll"  name="checkAll" /></th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
        <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Stipendiary ₹</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="chkclass" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="chkclass" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Christal Prema G.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="chkclass" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Kamalesan T.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="chkclass" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Palammal A.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="chkclass" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Thangapazham</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>400</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**jquery**

```
   $("#bonus_temp").each(function() {
  $("#bonus_temp").keyup(function(){
    var bonus = $("#bonus_temp").val();
    $("#bene_id").val(bonus);
  });
});
```

[image]

i want to add the input value ("#bonus_temp") to checkbox value ("#bene_id")
now my query is update the first row only. rest of the row is not working.
i'm using codeigniter to this project. i want to post datas for the table. i want to update the checked value to db. so i'm try to push the input value to check box.

Comment: You're using the ids bene_id and bonus_temp multiple times, but ids have to be unique. You can change them to classes instead.

Comment: not able to use different ids. this table id dynamic

Comment: Hey @mathew, I understand what you're trying to achieve but if textbox value is going to be same as checkbox value, doesn't it make it redundant? Why don't you try giving an id to the name of textbox? Eg- `<input type="text" id="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp['Your-unique-id-here']" value="" />`, and then get the value in your controller.

Comment: "_not able to use different ids. this table id dynamic_" What? Pretty sure you _can_ use different ids, "even" if the table is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would change the multiple used ids to classes to have valid HTML, you could do it like this:

```js
   $(".bonus_temp").keyup(function() {
     var bonus = $(this).val();
     $(this).closest("tr").find("td .bene_id").val(bonus);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
      <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
      <th class="text-right">Stipendiary ₹</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass bene_id" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass bene_id" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Christal Prema G.</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass bene_id" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Kamalesan T.</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass bene_id" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Palammal A.</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass bene_id" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Thangapazham</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="bonus_temp" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mathew Glad I was able to give some support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('tbody tr  #bonus_temp').keyup( function(){
       var bonus = $(this).val();
       $("tbody tr #bene_id").val(bonus);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This won't solve the problem as the OP has multiple elements with same id `bene_id`

Comment: I have to see it in action after @mathew tests it.

Comment: I didn't get it, is it Ok, if not we will try to solve it.